# jQuery dataTables: Exclude row from export based on criteria

Tags: jquery, datatables

In jQuery dataTables, is there a way to exclude a row from the Excel export if a certain criteria is met for a particular column in the table?

I currently have the following parameters set for the export button

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#resultTable').DataTable(
    {
        searching: false,
        pageLength: 50,
        order: [3, 'asc'],
        paging: true,
        deferRender: true,
        initComplete: function( settings, json ) {
            $('#resultContainer').show();
            $('#loading').hide();
        },
        /*dom: 'Bfrtip',*/
        /*buttons: ['excel'],*/
        buttons: [
        {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [19,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
                }
            }],
        columns: [
        {orderable: false},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{orderable: false},{orderable: false},{orderable: false}
        ],
    }
    
    );
    
    table
    .buttons()
    .container()
    .appendTo( '#menu' );
} );
```

However, I'd like to exclude from the export any rows in which the value of column 19 is set to "true".

EDITED: Here is an example of what the data table looks like. The filtering should be on the column with the header DNR.

| [Merge] | First Name | Last Name | Gender | City | State | Zip | Phone | Fax | Email | Email 2 | Primary Specialty | Secondary Specialty | Practice Name | Years | D | F | NPI | ME | DNR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [button] | Joe | Smith | M | Anytown | PA | 12345 | 123-456-7890 | 123-456-7891 | test@test.com | test@test.com | Primary | Secondary | Joe Smith | 5 | FALSE | FALSE | 12345 | 12345 | TRUE |
| [button] | Susan | Jones | F | Anytown | PA | 12346 | 123-456-7890 | 123-456-7891 | test@test.com | test@test.com | Primary | Secondary | Joe Smith | 6 | FALSE | FALSE | 12345 | 12345 | FALSE |
| [button] | John | Johnson | M | Anytown | PA | 12347 | 123-456-7890 | 123-456-7891 | test@test.com | test@test.com | Primary | Secondary | Joe Smith | 7 | FALSE | FALSE | 12345 | 12345 | FALSE |

If you look at the last column (DNR), in this sample only rows 2 and 3 would be included in the export, while row 1 would be omitted because it's value in that column is True.

Comment: could you show a sample with more rows? because we dont know how is formatted your array (i suppose) buttons  (if possible with row to eliminate)

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question to include the full function that is initializing the table as well as a sample of the data.

Comment: The `exportOptions` option also includes a `rows` sub-option (similar to the `columns` option you are already using). Both `rows` and `columns` can be provided with a function. For `rows` it can be: `rows: function ( idx, data, node ) { return data; }`. So, you can enhance that function to include conditional logic to selectively return only the rows you want to export. But we don't know how your rows are structured, so we cannot provide a specific solution. You can use `console.log( data );` to see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that worked for me.  As I was writing my table as it was being read from a database, I applied class="dnr" to any row that met the criteria I wanted to exclude.  I then changed my exportOptions parameter to exclude any rows that had that selector by setting rows to the jQuery selector ":not('.dnr')".  So the new button definition is:

```
buttons: [{ extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [19,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],
                    rows: ":not('.dnr')"
                }
         }],
```